# Add Character to field depending on state of check box

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am using access 2007, on a form I have two text boxes and a check box.

I have a field named Quote ID and Qshipnum and then the check box IsShip?.

I currently have the VBA on the checkbox isship? as follows

```
Private Sub QshipNum_AfterUpdate()

If Me.IsShip_.Value = True Then Me.QshipNum.Value = "S" + Me.QuoteID.Value

End If

End Sub
```

I would like to make the value of QshipNum S + whatever the quoteID is if the check mark is true. But currently I can't pull the concatenation of the two fields.

What can I do to pull quote ID as well as the S?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `&` instead of `+`:

```
If Me.IsShip_.Value = True Then Me.QshipNum.Value = "S" & Me.QuoteID.Value
```